# How to get button value + Bootstrap's Modal's Button value launched from PHP by first button

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get `clickMe` buttons value to confirm thing's from users by showing them confirm's modal. 
Button:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="clickMeValue" name="clickMe">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['clickMe'])){
   echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){
         $('#confirmModal').modal('show');
         });</script>"; // showing modal from php

//after shoeing modal from php

if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){
echo $_POST['confirm'];
echo "<br/>";
echo $_POST['clickMe'];     //this is not echoing           
            }
}       
            ?>
```

How can i get `clickMe` value inside of bootstraps modals confirm thing.

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the button and then here is how you can access the value of the clicked button ..

```
<button type="submit" id="my-button" class="btn btn-primary"  value="clickMeValue" name="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

And then ..

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#my-button').click(function() {

        var the_value = $(this).val();
        alert(the_value);

    });

});
```

Comment: is this will available in modals button? means when i click on modals button for confirmation?